# Javascript library or web application that allows me to build tutorials like the W3School ones

Tags: web-apps, library, javascript

I want to make notes of webpage development in a similar style to the one used on [W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_default):

[image]

I know I can just get the source of this page and start building a different page for me. But I'd like to have a perspective of different options before having this work. Is there any Javascript library that allows me to build tutorials like this one? With a piece of Javascript code ready for modifying while on the same screen the result of this Javascript code?

Alternatively, is there any web application of notes that allows me to make notes in a style similar to this one?

The possibility of creating interactive notes like this one from W3School would be very useful because of the functionality of changing it without necessarily saving it.